# porting sed command from linux to mac

Tags: unix, sed, porting

I am trying to run a bash analysis script on my mac but the sed command is not recognising '~'. The script works perfectly on my linux workstation. My script looks like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n '3~9p' file.txt | awk '{print $2}' > out.dat
```

When I run this on my mac I get "sed: 1: "3~9p": invalid command code ~".

Comment: (Unless you plan to distribute you sw..) Why not simply install another sed (as an alternative)? All future porting problems solved once for all.

Comment: Yes, I will do this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk` instead of `sed`,

```
awk 'BEGIN {s=3;i=9} NR==s{s+=i;print}' file.txt
```

Even more straight forward way is,

```
awk 'BEGIN {s=3;i=9} NR==s{s+=i;print $2}' file.txt > out.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU sed on your mac

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

then it should work like linux